# Potential causes of memory leaks in Android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm using `leakcanery` to find memory leaks in Android. I found and fixed all `Activity` leaks. (surprised to know there were so many BTW!).
I also added watch `refWatcher` for all my `Fragment`s.

**Question 1:** Is there anything else that I should watch that may cause noticeable memory leak?

**Question 2:** Isn't watching `Fragment` leaks redundant since a `Fragment` holds a reference to its `Activity`? I get the notification anyway, right? :-/

**Question 3:** When I check the memory monitor in android studio it shows the memory usage growth over time. Is it a sign of a giant memory leak or Android OS is kind and it is just giving me more memory? How can I find for sure?

Comment: you can check these: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html and eclipse MAT tool for more detail it ll help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anything else that I should watch that may cause a noticeable memory leak?

- Declaring a member field `static` almost guarantees a memory leak.
- Anonymous classes that last beyond the lifetime of the parent class, such as Volley `Request`s, also produce memory leaks, because they hold an implicit reference to the parent `Activity`, and if the `Activity` is gone before the request call completes, a memory leak takes place.

> Isn't watching `Fragment` leaks redundant since a `Fragment` holds a reference to its `Activity`?

A `Fragment` doesn't "hold" a reference to an `Activity`. The reference is supplied by the `FragmentManager`. But the framework manages this internally, so you don't need to worry about it.

> When I check the memory monitor in android studio it shows the memory usage growth over time. Is it a sign of a giant memory leak or Android OS is kind and it is just giving me more memory? How can I find for sure?

The memory growth of an app is natural, and the memory is cleaned up on subsequent passes of the garbage collector. In languages that have virtual machines and automatic garbage collectors, the programmer has little to no control over the allocation of memory. Beyond creating tiny memory leaks, there is very little a programmer can do to screw up the memory management process.

Comment: "Declaring a member field static almost guarantees a memory leak." - Sorry but there is no basis for that. I use static all the time and the Android source code itself has plenty of it.